# I want to compile the __init__.py file and install into other folder in yocto build system?

Tags: python, system, yocto

I want  to compile the __init__.py file and install into other folder in yocto build system?

Scenario:

> This basically in yocto build system. Third party library as zipped file
>   is available in download folder in my yocto build system. But that
>   library does not have the __init__.py file in the main folder. During
>   the building using bitbake command. It is unpacked and put the working
>   directory and the compile it. But __init__py and __init__.pyc file is
>   not available.

Any one have idea, how can I manually copy this __init__.py file and compile using .bb file in yocto builds system?

Answer (score 0):

You can place empty file **__init__.py** along with recipe and add it to  **SRC_URI** in this recipe:

```
SRC_URI = "http://www.aaa/bbb.tar.gz \
           file://__init__.py"
```

unpacker will just copy it to WORKDIR where the archive is unpacked.